# Download all remote js files with devtools

Tags: download, google-chrome-devtools

How to download all these files? Just saving a document won't help as these files are loaded asynchronously.

[image: Js files to download]

Comment: Who put the minus probably knows the answer?

Comment: There, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on any file in this sidebar and save it with help of ctrl-s shortcut.

Comment: Thank you, but imagine you have 100 files.